# Return the first iteration of the set of values even if they repeat,

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

It's hard to explain with words what I'm trying to accomplish so here's an example. Let's say we have the following table:

```
Customer    Group   BeginDate   ParentCustomer
1469046     3939    7/1/2010    1311044
1469046     3939    8/1/2010    1311044
1469046     4144    1/1/2011    1460224
1469046     4147    2/1/2011    1461557
1469046     3939    11/1/2013   1311044
1469046     3939    12/1/2013   1311044
1469046     3939    1/1/2014    1311044
1469046     3939    2/1/2014    1311044
1469046     3939    3/1/2014    1311044
1469046     3939    4/1/2014    1311044
1469046     3939    5/1/2014    1311044
1469046     3939    6/1/2014    1311044
1469046     3939    7/1/2014    1311044
1469046     3939    8/1/2014    1311044
1469046     587     9/1/2014    141274
1469046     587     10/1/2014   141274
1469046     587     11/1/2014   141274
1469046     587     12/1/2014   141274
```

And below is what I'm trying to get:

```
Customer    Group   BeginDate   ParentCustomer
1469046     3939    7/1/2010    1311044
1469046     4144    1/1/2011    1460224
1469046     4147    2/1/2011    1461557
1469046     3939    11/1/2013   1311044
1469046     587     9/1/2014     141274
```

So, basically, for each group I only want to display when it started.
I have the code that does what I need but what throws it off is the repeating group 3939. It will only display it once beginning in 7/1/2010.

Does anyone have any idea if this is possible and how I would go about doing it?

Comment: Hi dk2014, what have you tried as far as the query goes? You probably want to `GROUP BY Customer, Group, ParentCustomer`, and select `MIN(BeginDate)`

Comment: @dk2014, Is the reason that Group 3939 should repeat because of the gap in the months between 2010 and 2013?  And the other groups shouldn't repeat because they have sequential months?

Comment: All the data comes from several different tables that I didn't want to bore you with those details. I've done group by and ended up with a temp table that will have records as showed in the first snippet. And that's great but from there I need to get what's shown in the 2nd snippet. If I do GROUP BY Customer, Group, ParentCustomer and select MIN(BeginDate) this will result in group 3939 showing up only once with the BeginDate of 7/1/2010. I need it to show up twice (or more times if that's what happened).

Comment: Customer can belong to one group for few months, then switch to another group for few months and then go back to the first one and so one. There is never gap in the months. I might have not copied all the records but once the customer enters the system it has its group and it either stays in it or it switches to a new one and then switches to another one or goes back to the first one. Anything goes but the customer always belongs to a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *  
from 
(
SELECT *,
       LAG(Group, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY BeginDate) AS PreviousGroup
FROM table 
)
where PreviousGroup is null or PreviousGroup  <> group
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Blam. When I run this query however the WHERE clause throws an error as if it won't allow PreviousGroup alias to be referenced in the WHERE clause. If I replace Previous group with LAG(Group, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(BeginDate)) inside of WHERE clause it throws a different error

Comment: Oh, and also, it seems that you assumed that groups cannot repeat in the same year but this is not the case (it's the case in this example only). A customer could be in the group 3939 in Jan/Feb/Mar of 2015 and then in group 578 in April/May 2015 and then in group 3939 again in Jun/Jul 2015

Comment: No is does NOT assume groups cannot repeat.  Did you vote me down?

Comment: No, I did not vote you down. I just said I could not run the query. I still appreciate your help!

Comment: The subquery needs to be aliased and once it is it works fine. Thanks again!

Comment: I don't think you are going to find a more simple solution.  If it is correct you can give it a check.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Servier 2005 or SQL Server 2008 then you can use this.

```
SELECT  T.*
FROM    T
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 T2.[Group]    
            FROM    T AS T2
            WHERE   T2.Customer = T.Customer
            AND     T2.BeginDate < T.BeginDate
            ORDER BY T2.BeginDate DESC
        ) AS prev
WHERE   prev.[Group] != T.[Group]
OR      prev.[Group] IS NULL;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/047d3d/5)**

This simply uses [`OUTER APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to get the previous record for that customer, and removes the records where the previous group was the same, or null for the first record.

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later then you can do this with the [`LAG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) Function, but this may not perform better depending on the cardinality of your table:

```
SELECT  Customer, [Group], BeginDate, ParentCustomer
FROM    (   SELECT  Customer,
                    [Group],
                    BeginDate,
                    ParentCustomer,
                    PreviousGroup = LAG([Group]) OVER(PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY BeginDate)
            FROM    T
        ) AS T
WHERE   PreviousGroup != [Group]
OR      PreviousGroup IS NULL;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/047d3d/7)**

Comment: No it is not a gaps and island problem.  Did you vote me down?

Comment: I did not vote you down, although before your latest edit I would not have said your answer was useful as it contained incorrect logic and incorrect syntax. This *is* a gaps and islands problem, it is just a simplified version because the OP only cares about the first record of an island, not the full island. To quote the linked article *"whereas solving the islands problem involves finding the ranges of existing values."* - in this case a continuous range of the same group is considered an island.

Comment: Thank you GarethD for your answer! The other 2 answers seem to be working for me but I am still interested in your solution and will read more about it as I've never come across the 'gap and islands' problem before. I would vote all of you guys up since each one of you helped me but since I'm new on here it won't let me vote at all. Thanks again!

Comment: OK, not what I think of as gaps and island but not a problem

Comment: @Blam you are right, this is not a gaps and islands problem! I over complicated this. I have removed the section about gaps and islands, but have left my answer as it contains a solution for previous SQL Server Versions. I have also upvoted your answer to reverse the damage of whichever nasty person downvoted you without the decency of leaving a comment as to why!

Comment: @dk2014 No problem, as I have just said, I think I over complicated this, but I keep wavering back and forth as to whether it is not a gaps and islands problem, or if it is but just a simple version (since I could still solve it with traditional gaps and islands logic). Nonetheless, I think in most scenarios the LAG solution posted by Blam is going to be the best performing,

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT 'a'
                    FROM table t2
                    WHERE t2.group = t.group
                    AND DATEADD( DAY, 1, t2.BeginDate) = t.BeginDate
                  )
```

You can try with this solution and tell me if work

Comment: Thanks for your answer Javaluca. I think you meant to add a month, not a day, because when I make that correction it seems to be working. I'll have to do some more spot checking but it seems to be working in this particular case. Thanks!

Comment: My fault... first number in italian calendar is day not month so I misunderstood the question